# How do i stop app from crashing on RotateYTo?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, animation, xamarin.forms

I am writing a flashcard application in Xamarin.Forms where i use a form containing a label with the flashcard text. When the form is tapped it is going to flip 180 degrees and the text on the label is going to change.
The way i do this is by rotating the form with the "RotateYTo" to 90 degrees. After that i change the text on the label and change the rotation to -90 degrees. After that i use "RotateYTo" again to rotate the last 90 degrees (rotates from -90 back to 0) to make a seamless rotation.
Here's how it looks:

```
//Rotating the frame to half of the full rotation
            await frame.RotateYTo(90, 200, Easing.SinIn);

            //Changing the text on the label
            switch (label.Text)
            {
                case "A":
                    label.Text = "B";
                    break;
                case "B":
                    label.Text = "A";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //Changing the rotation to -90 degrees to make sure that the "180 degrees rotation" is seamingless and that the text isn't flipped
            frame.RotationY = -90;

            //Rotating the rest of the rotation
            await frame.RotateYTo(0, 200, Easing.SinOut);
```

And the corresponding XAML:

```
<!-- The frame that i will be rotating-->
        <Frame x:Name="frame" Grid.Row="1" Margin="40, 0, 40, 0" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="120">

            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

            <!-- A label that acts as the flashcard's text inside of the frame-->
            <Label x:Name="label" Text="A" FontSize="120" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        </Frame>
```

The problem is that a crash occurs every time the second RotateYTo function starts to execute. The app freezes immediately and the debugging is terminated. No exception is thrown and this "crash" seems only to appear on Android 9.

I have tested this on an Android 5.1 phone and it works fine, but on Android 9 it crashes both in the emulator and a test phone.

I thought that this might be due to the two rotation functions being executed at the same time (due to the await keyword) and have therefore tried to wait for the first RotateYTo function to finish:

```
[...]

//Waiting for the previous animation to finish
            while (frame.RotationY != 90)
            {

            }

            //Changing the rotation to -90 degrees to make sure that the "180 degrees rotation" is seamingless and that the text isn't flipped
            frame.RotationY = -90;

            //Rotating the rest of the rotation
            await frame.RotateYTo(0, 200, Easing.SinOut);
```

I have also tried adding a "ConfigureAwait" method to my first function, both with "true" and "false" as arguments:

```
//Rotating the frame to half of the full rotation
            await frame.RotateYTo(90, 200, Easing.SinIn).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Furthermore, i have tried to save the animation as a separate task and then "waiting" for it before the next animation:

```
//Rotating the frame to half of the full rotation
            Task<bool> animFrameY = frame.RotateYTo(90, 200, Easing.SinIn);
            await animFrameY;

[...]

//Waiting for the first animation to finish
            animFrameY.Wait();
```

I also tried to terminate (force stop) the first animation regardless of it being finished or not, before executing the second animation by using the "CancelAnimations" method on my frame:

```
//Terminating all animations on the frame
            ViewExtensions.CancelAnimations(frame);
```

All of that, however, didn't work, and the application still freezes and no exception is thrown.

I want the frame to be rotated 180 degrees and halfways through the text on the label should change without being flipped.
I have tried removing the "await" keyword on the first animation, which prevents the crash but then this part just gets skipped without being displayed which both looks ugly and is not what i need.

EDIT:
I have now uploaded this project as a GitHub repository:

https://github.com/KMilkevych/Flashcard-application

Comment: **I have tested this on an Android 5.1 phone and it works fine, but on Android 9 it crashes both in the emulator and a test phone.**, you mean that it works at Android 5.1, but have crash at android 9? can you provide one sample on github, I will wodnload your sample to test.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I have now uploaded this project to my GitHub page:
https://github.com/KMilkevych/Flashcard-application

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that updating the UI controls is performed by the UI thread. Xamarin.Forms provides a handy [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms) which ensures that actions are being performed by this UI thread. Here is an example how you can "wrap" your rotation code

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => 
{
   await frame.RotateYTo(0, 200, Easing.SinOut);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution by invoking both animations on the UI thread as you showed.
It prevents the crash, but the first animation is not being displayed at all (it just gets skipped) and only the second animation is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, If I use TapGestureRecognizer like your sample, sometimes I don't have any effects, so I try to use PanGestureRecognizer to do this, I don't have any problem, and achieve your goals.

```
 <Frame
        x:Name="frame"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="40,0,40,0"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
        HeightRequest="120">

        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />-->
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

        <!--  A label that acts as the flashcard's text inside of the frame  -->
        <Label
            x:Name="label"
            FontSize="120"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="A"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

    </Frame>
```

Please put your rotate code in PanGestureRecognizer.PanUpdated event.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, i have tried your solution, but putting the code inside a "PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated event" doesn't seem to change anything except for the action required to trigger the event. I still encounter a freeze/crash during the execution of the animation.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I test you sample again, now It works fine, I don't get any issue. I put my screenshot on reply. You can also use PanGestureRecognizer to do this, but you need to use finger swipe.

Comment: This might be an issue with my device only then; I have uploaded a video of the crash occuring on my pc (i couldn't add it to the question since the video is too large):

http://www.mediafire.com/file/2j1t2devzmtw4kg/animationAppCrash.mp4/file

Comment: @Kostyantyn, You said  it just crash on Android 9, other device works fine, so I think there is no problem  with your code, you can try to create one thread at github for getting more discussion.